# whats the benefits of json_encode unescape slashes?

Tags: php, json

Hello some time ago i had the expertslead test and saw that they want unescaped slashes, normal json_encode generate the following:

```
"https:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/"
```

but they want the version with JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

Can anyone explaine me why? whats the benefits of it? normaly the libs does a correct interpretation of it

Comment: JSON spec does not require escaping of `/` but the PHP implementation does escape them for some historic reason.  I would assume that you should always use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` or you will have to strip them latter.

Comment: ah okay thanks because i have seen thaht all my c#/js libs had no problems to read it direct